# Log statements in a Groovy class not printing the arguments

Tags: gradle

I am working with a Gradle project that is later built and tested by a Jenkins pipeline.

The Groovy class:

```
class ConfigurationPluginInitBase implements Plugin<Project> {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigurationPluginInitBase.class)
.
.
.
protected void configureDependenciesResolution(Project project) {
.
.
.
File file = new File(project.getRootDir(), 'buildInfo.json')
def rewriteDependency = project.hasProperty('rewriteDependency') ? project.property('rewriteDependency') : null

logger.info('Does the buildInfo.json exist??? {}' , file.exists())
logger.info('The list of the dependencies should be re-written: {}' , rewriteDependency)
.
.
.
if (rewriteDependency) {
   def listToUpdate = rewriteDependency.split(',')
   logger.info('List is : {}' , listToUpdate)
 .
 .
 .
 }  
}

}
```

The above method is triggered via a Jenkins pipeline, the partial console output:

```
Configuring Dependencies Resolution
Does the buildInfo.json exist??? true
The list of the dependencies should be re-written:
List is :
```

I even tried casting 'rewriteDependency' and 'listToUpdate' to Object but it didn't help.

Note:If I use println, the output is something like:

```
Configuring Dependencies Resolution
Does the buildInfo.json exist??? true
The list of the dependencies should be re-written: 
DAP_Framework:DAP_Framework_CLI:1.2.2-integration.332a45d
List is : [DAP_Framework:DAP_Framework_CLI:1.2.2-integration.332a45d]
```

Comment: Are you sure `rewriteDependency` is not the empty string `""`?

Comment: No, if I use println, it works. I will edit the question to include this point.